# Count values over a certain number in a row

Tags: r

I read in a data frame like this:

```
site elevation sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5 sp6 sp7 sp8 sp9 sp10 sp11 sp12 sp13 sp14 sp15 sp16 sp17 sp18
1       1.2     0   5   2   1   2   0   1   0   2    0    1    3    0    0    0    0    0    0
2       3.9     0   4   2   0   3   0   0   0   0    2    0    2    0    0    1    0    0    0
3       4.4     0   2   1   1   2   0   1   0   0    1    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0
4       5.5     0   4   3   0   5   0   1   0   2    1    0    3    0    0    2    0    0    0
5       9.0     0   3   2   0   1   0   1   0   2    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
```

sp is species number

For each site, I want to count the number of species that have 2 or more

So want to get a list like [6,6,4,7,4] or an array with the siteID and those values

I've been stuffing around with nested for loops but there's gotta be a more elegant way to do it...

Answer (score 7):

Not the same as your output, but...

```
> rowSums(dat[grepl("sp",colnames(dat))]>=2)
[1] 5 5 3 6 3
```

Comment: Thank you!

No not same output - went up to sp20 but I cut the last 2 off

Comment: @BenjaminBarrett You can adapt the regex pattern in `grep`, just try `rowSums(dat[, grep('sp[1-9]\\b|sp1[0-8]', colnames(dat))] > 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative with `apply`:

```
apply(df[, 3:ncol(df)], 1, \(x) sum(x >= 2))

[1] 5 5 3 6 3
```

and a `dplyr` way:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(
    site = site, 
    species_count = sum(across(starts_with("sp"), ~ .x >= 2))
  )

 site species_count
  <int>         <int>
1     1             5
2     2             5
3     3             3
4     4             6
5     5             3
```

Comment: I was trying with apply but couldn't work out what function to use...

Comment: I was trying with apply() but couldn't work out what function to use...

I didn't realise you actually define a function within apply()...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the tidyverse methods you can pivot the table into the long format, filter the values smaller than 2 and then groupby on site:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('sp')) %>% 
  filter(value >= 2) %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  count()
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   site [5]
   site     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     5
2     2     5
3     3     3
4     4     6
5     5     3
```

Comment: Thank you - I think I might have to use that way later, as I'll need more records in table form

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `dplyr` with `mutate` and `rowSums` and `pull` to get a vector with he results:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(n = rowSums(select(., starts_with("sp")) >= 2)) %>%
  pull(n)
#> [1] 5 5 3 6 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you...playing around with dplyr now